# Convert 4 bytes to integer using struct

Tags: python

I have a microcontroller connected to my computer via I2C connection, which sends back 1 byte of data at a time. I am trying to send a 4-byte number to the python program. I receive it in an array of individual bytes like this `[123,45,67,89]`.

I need to convert that back into an integer in python. I am trying to use struct.unpack to do this, but I cannot get the data format correct. I am trying to get it in the form:

```
struct.unpack("I",b'x12\x34\x56\x78)
```

I don't know how to get the 4 bytes into the form required by struct. I can convert the numbers to hex, but don't know how to string them together.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. Can you edit your question and elaborate more?

Comment: I reformed it. Hopefully it is clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert it to a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) and pass that to `struct.unpack()`.

```
import struct

data = [123, 45, 67, 89]

# Show hex values of data.
print(list('%02x' % b for b in data))  # -> ['7b', '2d', '43', '59']

# Convert to 4 byte unsigned integer data interpreting data as being in 
# little-endian byte order.
value = struct.unpack("<I", bytearray(data))[0]
print(hex(value))  # -> 0x59432d7b
```